# Using IF Array in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I am trying to calculate X/Y/Z, where the value for Z is in a single column C but the values for each of X and Y are selected from two columns apiece, with the higher of the two cell values being used.

I can paste the intermediate value into a hidden column of course by doing

```
=IF(A1>B1, A1/C1, B1/C1)
```

and then repeating the formula to calculate X/Y/Z using the intermediate value instead of Y/Z, but how do I sidestep that and combine everything into one array?

Comment: Add example data.

Answer (score 0):

If you already figured out the formula in a helper column, just turn it into a super formula where you combine everything together.

```
=IF(A1>B1, A1/C1, B1/C1) / D1
```

Or however it is you have your fields setup. You aren't limited to doing just a single formula in each cell. However, if you have the problem solved with helper columns, why worry about making it into a super formula at all? Just leave it. It will probably be easier to maintain later that way.